# using c++ aggregate initialization in std::make_shared

Tags: c++, c++11

Per my understanding, the following code constructs an object of type `Foo` and then moves that object into the memory allocated by `std::make_shared`

```
struct Foo
{
    std::string s;
    int i;
    char c;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    auto foo = std::make_shared<Foo>(Foo{"hello", 5, 'c' });
}
```

Is it possible to [aggregate initialize](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) `Foo` directly into the memory allocated by `std::make_shared`?

Comment: I don't think this is possible.

Comment: See [this](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4462.html). You might get your wish someday.

Comment: Are you able to change Foo's definition ?

Comment: Nope, I cannot change Foo's definition.

Comment: C++20 allows direct (non-list) initialization of aggregates largely to support this use case.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could create an adapter with a variadic constructor template to forward the arguments, something like:

```
template<class T>
struct aggregate_adapter : public T {
    template<class... Args>
    aggregate_adapter(Args&&... args) : T{ std::forward<Args>(args)... } {}
};
```

And then you can do:

```
auto foo = std::make_shared<aggregate_adapter<Foo>>("hello", 5, 'c');
```

Since `aggregate_adapter<Foo>` and `Foo` are related, `foo` is convertible to `std::shared_ptr<Foo>` as well.

### Caveats

---

Unfortunately, the use of forwarding also makes it impossible to brace-init any of the members like `std::make_shared<aggregate_adapter<Foo>>({'h','e','l','l','o'}, 5, 'c');` without specifying the type explicitly, but the same restriction applies to make_shared already.

Comment: I got a compilation error with this in vs12 `main.cpp(24): error C2797: 'Foo': list initialization inside member initializer list or non-static data member initializer is not implemented`

Comment: @tcb: VS12 doesn't have very good support for C++11 so this is unsurprising, you could try upgrading to VS15?

Comment: Great solution, melak47! I'm using this to initialize a class containing a bunch of const std::functions with lambda expressions (an alternative to standard runtime polymorphism via virtual functions). Thanks!

Comment: Another caveat is that this solution wouldn't work with structs that are declared as `final`, although I think that wouldn't be much of a problem in practice

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution does not work if `Foo`'s move constructor is deleted: https://godbolt.org/z/WxbscKesc

Answer (score 4):

The inheritance solution feels a bit overkill to me, and adds a bit of readability confusion because the make_shared template is not your type.

Unaware readers might be confused about this aggregate_adapter part.

Here is an alternative:

```
#include <iostream>
struct Foo
{
    std::string s;
    int i;
    char c;
};

template<typename T, typename... Args>
std::shared_ptr<T> MakeAggregateShared(Args&&... args)
{
    return std::make_shared<T>(T{ std::forward<Args>(args)... });
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    auto foo = MakeAggregateShared<Foo>("hello", 5, 'c');
}
```

Comment: It should be noted that this solution wouldn't work if an aggregate member contains a member with deleted move constructor

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to make `std::make_shared` work here. However, one can construct a `shared_ptr` from an rvalue even for objects with **private constructors** and **no copy or move constructors** using [a new-expression, where the initializer is a braced-init-list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization).

[Example](https://godbolt.org/z/7aG4Gsa7W):

```
#include <memory>

class A {
private:
    A() {}
public:
    A(const A&) = delete;
    A(A&&) = delete;
    static A construct() {
        return A();
    }
};

int main() {
   auto a = std::shared_ptr<A>(new A{A::construct()});
}
```

In this situation, @melak47's answer does not work as it depends on rvalue references and needs a working move constructor.

A real-world example of such a situation would be exposing an iterator-type class designed to be only constructed locally as a Python object via pybind11.

Comment: It works but with overhead; now `shared_ptr` won't allocate the object and the control block together.

Answer (score 0):

In C++20 you can just write

```cpp
std::make_shared<Foo>("hello", 5, 'c');
```

(Elaborating on Davis Herring's comment.)