# Is there something like std::emplace_shared<T>?

Tags: c++, std

It should do this, except without the extra construction:

```
template<typename T, typename ...Args>
std::shared_ptr<T> emplace_shared(Args&&... args) {
    std::shared_ptr<T> p = std::make_shared<T>();
    *p = T{std::forward<Args>(args)...};
    return p;
}

struct A {
    int a;
    float b;
    std::string c;
};

void main() {
    std::shared_ptr<A> p = emplace_shared<A>(1, 2.0f, "3");
}
```

The idea is it can be used like `A{1, 2.0f, "3"}` but with `shared_ptr`.

Comment: Something like [`std::make_shared`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared)?

Comment: I see your problem. `A` is an aggregate. Good news is, C++20 solves your problem, and `make_shared` will work. But of course, that doesn't help you *now*. You can give [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35298989/using-c-aggregate-initialization-in-stdmake-shared) a look. It's about the same problem.

Comment: `std::make_shared<A>(A{1, 2.0f, "3"})`?